# Kendo ui autocomplete using WCF

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, entity-framework-4, kendo-ui

I would like to display both description and Date in my kendo auto complete. THe following code will display as expected except the date. The date is displaying weird format

```
xml:
<d:SDate  m:type="Edm.DateTime">2012-11-21T18:30:51.097</d:SDate>
```

if i type Nike
it will come up Nike (/Date(13534560000)/)

$("#titles").kendoAutoComplete({
                minLength: 3,
                dataTextField: "SDesc",
                dataValueField: "RefID",
                template: '${ data.SDesc } ' + '(' + '${ data.SDate }' + ')',

```
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverPaging: true,
                pageSize: 20,
                transport: {
                    read: "http://localhost:54329/HH_WcfDataService.svc/Product"
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using [kendo.parseDate](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#parsedate) in your template:

```
template: '${ data.SDesc } ' + '(' + '${ kendo.parseDate(data.SDate) }' + ')',
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/ekogex/1/edit

Comment: I have never seen that /Date(xyz)/ syntax before Q3 release, where may I read about it?

Comment: This is how Microsoft decided to serialize dates to JSON. Not invented by Kendo :) Here is more info: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_serialize_dates_to_json.ashx

Comment: Hi Atanas, thank you. Is there any way we can format date to dd/MM/yyyy format?. Please advise?

Comment: Atanas, sorry again for taking advantage of your position in Telerik ;-) what I meant is that Q3 is the first release able of parsing it,isn't it? If so, which other cool feature includes Q3 release, is there any documentation?

Comment: @EmilianoBartolome http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new/release-notes/q3-2012-version-2012-3-1114.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the *weird* date format because the `Date` is actually stored as a number. You need to format it to your desired format `yyyy-mm-dd`, `mm-dd-yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy`,... Try using `kendo.format` and/or `kendo.toString` (check http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting for information on displaying dates in your local/desired format).
I think that `kendo.toString` will work for you since it accepts a `number` as argument for dates (http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#tostring)

Comment: Thanks Emiliano, but no luck yet. Any other idea?